# Ternary operator usages?

Tags: java, ternary-operator, conditional-statements

I know that **ternary operator** is used of doing a variable assignment after a evaluating a logical condition.

So:

```
String s = (logicalVariable) ? "Hello" : "Bye, bye";
```

**or,**

```
int x = (5<3) ? 10 : 100;
```

would be usage examples, right?

But what if Idon't really want to do a variable assignment but to set a sentence or even a piece of code, for example:

```
if (inventario.containsKey(item))
        return inventario.get(item);
    else return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

Can these lines be writen in a *one line expression*, probably by using the ternary operator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
return inventario.containsKey(item)? inventario.get(item); Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

The first part just need to evaluate to a `boolean`

Comment: Thank you, just I googled (not enough, ok) and first sites I saw mentioned ternary operator to work only for variable assignments. 
What other uses are there?

Answer (score 5):

```
return inventario.containsKey(item) ?  inventario.get(item) : Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```